# Use local datasource instead of specifying it in standalone.xml (WildFly)

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss, datasource, wildfly

I usually have my datasources listed in standalone.xml like (just a sample):

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDB" pool-name="myDB" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://mysql/myDB</connection-url>
    <driver>mysql</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>root</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
    <statement>
        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

MySQL driver is installed to WildFly. I know that one can add datasources to `webapp --> WEB-INF --> my-ds.xml`

But when I deploy my buildet war to WildFly I get

```
16:59:15,121 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 3) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "poc")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.data-source.\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.testDB\" is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"]
}
16:59:15,124 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 3) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "poc.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.data-source.\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.testDB\" is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"]
}
```

My question is:

How can I move my datasource definitions from standalone.xml to my project and make it work when deploying to WildFly

Comment: How did you install your mysql driver?

Comment: it is installed as a module, I solved this already

Comment: Have you? What is the name of the driver in the WildFly configuration? Please run the jboss-cli.sh and add the output of `ls subsystem=datasources` to your question, because you do not appear to have a driver named `mysql`.

Comment: driver is definitely installed. please, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already figured out how to solve the problem.

First is to add a `boss-deployment-structure.xml` (to `WEB-INF` f.e.) where one has to specify the driver:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.mysql" services="export">
                <imports>
                    <include path="META-INF**"/>
                    <include path="com**"/>
                    <!-- assuming user of the driver is com.something -->
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Then I add my datasources by `-ds.xml` pattern.
(WildFly 10 says actually it is deprecated...)

In my `persistence.xml` I can now use the datasources.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing datasource, -ds.xml in application,you can put it in deployments directory.